# Webpack 3 devserver hot module replacement through apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, webpack, mod-proxy, hot-module-replacement, mod-proxy-wstunnel

I have a project where we use webpack's devserver for local development. We also have the hot module replacemet for live reload: [hot module replacement](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/)

We have our front end running in docker. With that front end, we have also apache's mod_proxy. Idea is to have all http call's to go through the mod_proxy. So browser will send http to mod_proxy, that will then proxy to front end. This works well without hot module replacement. But for some reason, we are unable to get the hot module replacement work. I guess it is because hot module replacement uses web sockets, and tunneling web socket call's through apache's mod_proxy is not enabled by default?

Has someone been able to achieve this? How did you manage to do it? What configurations were needed in devserver / hot module replacement? Did you use apache's mod_proxy web socket tunnel: [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html), and how did you configure it? You do not need to answer to all the sub questions listed before, I just need the info on how to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

A. Yes. I could get this working with the following configuration in Apache2

```
<Location /sockjs-node>
        RequestHeader set Host "localhost:4200"
        RequestHeader set Origin "http://localhost:4200"
        ProxyPass ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node
        ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node
        CacheDisable on
</Location>
<Location /sockjs-node/info>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info
        CacheDisable on
</Location>
```

B. My apache2 server has mod_proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel enabled.

C. I am using this configuration for my angular 7 development.